# Non-angular submit buttons stop working when including angular lib

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

I've just added angular library to all my website since I use it for nice animations in the menu. I have noticed though that since I did, all submit buttons stopped working. I'm simply using common html, like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdateDates" value="Update">
</form>
```

Common "button" elements still work fine.

I did notice that forms suddenly has classes ng-pristine and ng-valid added to it automatically. Do I really have to use angular operations for all submit buttons for it to work? Is there a way to work around this, to "disactivate" angular library for certain forms? Thank you!

Comment: angular is a lot more than a library. Using a whole framework just for menu animations sounds like major overkill.

Comment: There is probably some script that is overriding the form submit event.  Angular doesn't do this out of the box.  Try removing your script files one at a time until the forms start working again.  Then you can post the relevant script to the question.